# Formula based on first monday or tuesday etc of the week Part 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So in the first past I was using the formula

`=DATE(2022,{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12},7-WEEKDAY(DATE(2022,{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12},1)-5,3))`

To calculate the first monday of each month.

We further made it interactive by having the user put the year in cell A1 and the day of the week we need the first of each month of in cell A2 to get the first of each month by using

```
=LET(yr,A1,
    wkdy,MATCH(PROPER(A2),{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"},0),
    mnt,SEQUENCE(12),
    DATE(yr,mnt,1)+MOD(8-WEEKDAY(DATE(yr,mnt,1),10+wkdy),7))
```

Thank you to Scott Craner for that bit of code. Now what we are looking to do is take one final step further. So rather than putting a year in cell A1, how could it be done that you put in say todays date (or any date for that matter) into cell A1, then the day into cell A2 and have it calculate out the next 12 first Monday's or Tuesday's or whatever day is in cell A2 for the next 12 months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying Scott's formula a bit,
you can try:

```
=LET(dt, DATE(YEAR(A1),SEQUENCE(12,,MONTH(A1)+1),8),
wkdy, MATCH(LEFT(A2,3),{"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"},0),
dt-(WEEKDAY(dt-wkdy)))
```

[image]

Comment: August 8th, 2022; January 9th, 2023; May 8th, 2023 in the example are in the second week of the month.

Comment: @P.b Thanks for pointing that out. Dumb error. Glad you caught it.  And I was able to make a further simplification.

Comment: Nice one. If you leave out the `+1` for the MONTH it'll start from the first weekday of mentioned month and counts from there. `=LET(dt, DATE(YEAR(A1),SEQUENCE(12,,MONTH(A1)),8),wkdy, MATCH(LEFT(A2,3),{"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"},0),dt-(WEEKDAY(dt-wkdy)))`. Better to read than the one I answered.

Comment: @P.b Yes. But in his question, the OP wrote "*have it calculate out the **next** 12*", so I started at the next month.

Comment: Ah correct. I was confusing things with the previous question.

Comment: Thank you both for the help. I am much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

Edit (there was a fault in my previous post, so I tweaked Scott's version):

```
=LET(yr,YEAR(A1),    
     wkdy,MATCH(PROPER(A2),{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"},0),    
     mnt,SEQUENCE(12,,MONTH(A1)),
DATE(yr,mnt,1)+MOD(8-WEEKDAY(DATE(yr,mnt,1),10+wkdy),7))
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think you quite understand. So the idea is to not have to change the formula at all but rather base the formula on the input of the user. So the formula would go into cell A3
cell A1 = todays date (or any date for that matter)
cell A2 = the day you you want referenced (say Thursday)

cell A3 = would then calculate the first thursday of each month for the next 12 months.

Comment: That's what it does, except for the day you need a number, but you can tweak Scott's earlier solution to include the translation from text to have it meet that condition. Try the formula. It uses the date of A1 and starts with the first Monday of that month, followed by the first Monday of the following months. A2 would be the last `3` in my formula.

Comment: See added version in edit

Comment: With Scotts revision, it worked for the first day, but when I changed it from Monday to Tuesday, I just got all #NUM! errors. To add to that when I changed it back to Monday it worked again.

Comment: I couldn't find the flaw, but encountered the same. I switched to tweaking Scott's formula.